# Unable to list associated assessments in coursedetails view

Tags: android

I've created two views coursedetails and assessment details. I am having issues pulling the associated assessments into the coursedetails view. Below is the code I have

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.assessmentrecyclerview);
        repository = new Repository(getApplication());
        final AssessmentAdapter assessmentAdapter = new AssessmentAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(assessmentAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        List<Assessment> filteredAssessments = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Assessment c : repository.getAssessments()) {
            if (c.getCourseID() == courseID) filteredAssessments.add(c);
        }
        assessmentAdapter.setAssessments(filteredAssessments);
```

I've tried changing the assessmentID to courseID